# ppo algorithms : ValueError: Layer "my_model_7" expects 3 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received:

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I tried running the code from a book to study the PPO (Proximal Policy Optimization) algorithm. However, I encountered an error.

It seems that the code is only accepting states_t with a shape of (1, 1, 4), but it should accept three inputs as the input requires.

Below is the code and its output.

I believe there is no issue with the data shape according to my understanding:

> ValueError: Layer "my_model_7" expects 3 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 1, 4) dtype=float32>]

It seems that only states_t is being accepted as input during model.fit when customizing the model, while the other two inputs, action_matrixs_t and advantages_t, are not being accepted.

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
        def train_step(self, data):
            in_datas, out_action_probs = data
            states, action_matrixs, advantages = in_datas[0], in_datas[1], in_datas[2]
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                y_pred = self(states, training=True)
                new_policy = K.max(action_matrixs*y_pred, axis=-1)
                old_policy = K.max(action_matrixs*out_action_probs, axis=-1)
                r = new_policy/(old_policy)
                clipped = K.clip(r, 1-LOSS_CLIPPING, 1+LOSS_CLIPPING)
                loss = -K.minimum(r*advantages, clipped*advantages)

            trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
            gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
            self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

    def build_model_actor(self):
        input_states = Input(shape=(1,self.state_size), name='input_states')
        input_action_matrixs = Input(shape=(1,self.action_size), name='input_action_matrixs')
        input_advantages = Input(shape=(1,self.value_size), name='input_advantages')

def train_mini_batch(self):

        if len(self.states) == 0:
            return

        states_t = np.array(self.states)
        states_next_t = np.array(self.states_next)
        action_matrixs_t = np.array(self.action_matrixs)
        action_probs_t = np.array(self.action_probs)
        rewards_t = np.array(self.rewards)

        values = self.model_critic.predict(states_t)
        values_next = self.model_critic.predict(states_next_t)`

# I attempted to verify whether the data types of the inputs match correctly.

# this is result of model.summary

Model: "my_model_8"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_states (InputLayer)      [(None, 1, 4)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 dense_17 (Dense)               (None, 1, 24)        120         ['input_states[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
 input_action_matrixs (InputLay  [(None, 1, 2)]      0           []                               
 er)                                                                                              
                                                                                                  
 input_advantages (InputLayer)  [(None, 1, 1)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 output (Dense)                 (None, 1, 2)         50          ['dense_17[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 170
Trainable params: 170
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Model: "model_8"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_states (InputLayer)   [(None, 1, 4)]            0         
                                                                 
 dense_18 (Dense)            (None, 1, 24)             120       
                                                                 
 output (Dense)              (None, 1, 1)              25        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 145
Trainable params: 145
Non-trainable params: 0
```

and here are inpuy data results:

states_t

```
[[[-0.00982568 -0.02236664 -0.04371476 -0.03285118]]

 [[-0.01027302 -0.21683532 -0.04437178  0.24572513]]

 [[ 0.06717221  0.38289127 -0.20573643 -0.96793896]]]
```

action_matrixs_t

```
[[[1. 0.]]
 [[0. 1.]]
 [[1. 0.]]
 [[0. 1.]]
 [[1. 0.]]]
```

advantages_t

```
[[[-137.71219637]]
 [[-149.00249989]]
 [[-372.09516106]]
 [[-400.56301659]]]
```